# EFCore is loading relationships that I haven't specified include on, is this some setting somewhere?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

When I call for certain entities some of the relationships are pulled back even though they have not been specified in the .Include.

My problem:

```
 _context.EntityABCs.ToList()
```

will bring back one of the properties when it shouldnt:

```
{
   public List<SomeOtherEntity> Relationship1 = null;
   public List<AnotherEntity> Relationship2 = new List<AnotherEntity>(){{},{},{}....};
}
```

even though it should only do so if you include it as so:

```
_context.EntityABCs
.Include(x => x.Relationship2)
.ToList()
```

I have NO idea why its doing this. What makes it stranger is that the query outputted is correct (to debug console) ie.

```
select propa, propb ... from EntityABCs
```

**NOTE:** I am setting up context properties like:

```
public DbSet<EntityABC> EntityABCs { get; set; }
```

with the mappings done like:

```
_ = new EntityABCMap(builder.Entity<EntityABC>());
```

where the mapper class is like:

```
public class EntityABCMap
    {
        public EntityABCMap(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityABC> entityTypeBuilder)
        {
            entityTypeBuilder.ToTable("EntityABCs", "dbo");
            entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            entityTypeBuilder.Property(t => t.Id).UseIdentityColumn();

            entityTypeBuilder.Property(e => e.EnumProp).HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<EnumTypeHere>());

            entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(t => t.Relationship1).WithOne(x => x.EntityABC);
            entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(t => t.Relationship2).WithOne(x => x.EntityABC);
        }
}
```

In the example above Relationship1&2 are used, the mapping HasMany-WithOne is also done in those maps.

**NOTE:** This is .NETCORE 3.1 project with EFCore 3.19 and EFCore SQL Server 5

Does anyone have anything to suggest?

Comment: How do you know that related entity is loaded? And that other one is not? If you are still connected to context relations can be fetched.

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic break point inspection

Comment: can you try this: _context.EntityABCs..AsNoTracking().ToList() and check then?

Comment: Yeah correct (returns the bare bones). I did also just identify its because of a middleware, commented out the middleware and it worked - although i do need the middleware

Comment: yeah will just have to use this it seems

Answer (score 0):

Will have to use AsNoTracking() (as Nemanja Todorovic suggested) because the entities are loaded in middleware before the request execution

Comment: Then you should ask yourself the question why the middleware uses the same context as the actual request.

Comment: @GertArnold it wasn't dbcontext pooling as i thought and its not singleton (from di setup as transient). Just to be clear am also injecting it to each place its required (its not created with new anywhere - in my code at least)

Comment: @Gert - "The AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a scoped lifetime by default." is why

Comment: Then the next question is: can the middleware do the same task without attaching entities to the context? Or by clearing the change tracker afterwards?

Comment: Yeah thats what i did, cleared the change tracker. Nice one @GertArnold!